# Implementing an l2 loss into a tensorflow Sequential regression model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I created a keras- tensorflow model, much influenced by 
[this guide](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) 
which looks like

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time 
import numpy as np
import sys
from keras import losses


model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(nodes,activation = tf.keras.activations.relu, input_shape=[len(data_initial.keys())]))
model.add(layers.Dense(64,activation = tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse',    # <-------- Here we define the loss function 
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr= 0.01,
                                                beta_1 = 0.01,
                                                beta_2 = 0.001,
                                                epsilon= 0.03),
                                                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])
model.fit(train_data,train_labels,epochs = 200)
```

It is a regression model and instead of the **loss = 'mse'** I would like to use 
[tf keras mse loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MSE) together with an **L2 regularization term**. The question is

- How can I add a predefined regularizer function (I think, it is [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/l2_loss) ) into the **model.compile** statement.
- How can I write a completely custom loss function and add it to **model.compile**.

Answer (score 2):

You can add regularization as either a layer parameter or as a layer.

Use it as a layer parameter looks like below

```
model.add(layers.Dense(8, 
          kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01),
          activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))
```

#### Sample code with first dense layer regularized and a custom loss function

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import time 
import numpy as np
import sys
from keras import losses
from keras import regularizers
import keras.backend as K


model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(8,activation = tf.keras.activations.relu, input_shape=(8,), 
                       kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), 
                       activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0.01)))

model.add(layers.Dense(4,activation = tf.keras.activations.relu))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1, noise_shape=None))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))


def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_true - y_pred)**2

model.compile(loss=custom_loss,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr= 0.01,
                                                beta_1 = 0.01,
                                                beta_2 = 0.001,
                                                epsilon= 0.03),
                                                metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

model.fit(np.random.randn(10,8),np.random.randn(10,1),epochs = 1)
```

Comment: How would you do this if you have a custom training loop? Do you add the regularization yourself, or does it still take into accoun the keras parameters? :)